# removing last comma from string rtrim

Tags: php, trim

Can't seem to get rtrim to work and I don't understand why:

```
$array = array("top" => array("one" => "inner one", "two" => "inner two"));

foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
  $form[$key] = array();
  $sql = "INSERT INTO $key SET ";
  foreach (array_keys($array[$key]) as $field) {
    array_push($form[$key], $field);
    $sql .= $field." = '".$array[$key][$field]."',";
  }
}
  rtrim($sql,',');
  $sql .= ";";
```

Why would this not get rid of the last comma?

it keeps printing out this:

```
INSERT INTO top SET one = 'inner one',two = 'inner two',;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to assign the `rtrim` to `$sql` like that:

```
$sql = trim($sql, ",");
```

Answer (score 1):

Better way is to use `implode()`. Example:

```
$array = array("top" => array("one" => "inner one", "two" => "inner two"));
foreach($array as $key=>$val){
    $form = array();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO $key SET ";
    foreach ($val as $k=>$field) {
        array_push($form, $k."='".$field."'");
    }
    $sql .= implode(",",$form);
    //echo $sql;
}
```

**Output:**

```
INSERT INTO top SET one='inner one',two='inner two'
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to overwrite $sql variable with rtrim result

```
 $array = array("top" => array("one" => "inner one", "two" => "inner two"));

 foreach (array_keys($array) as $key) {
   $form[$key] = array();
   $sql = "INSERT INTO $key SET ";
   foreach (array_keys($array[$key]) as $field) {
     array_push($form[$key], $field);
     $sql .= $field." = '".$array[$key][$field]."',";
   }
 }
 $sql = rtrim($sql,',');
 $sql .= ";";
```